# Autohotkey - if left mouse button is not depressed

Tags: autohotkey

Looking to do something like this:

```
if leftmousebutton not depressed
    some other action
```

Does anybody know how I would go about coding that?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
GetKeyState, state, LButton 

if state = U
    some other action
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if !GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    msgbox the left mouse button is not depressed.
```

[GetKeyState() documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about autohotkey, but in the event the left mouse button is pressed down, set `leftMouseButtonPressed = true`, and when it is released, set `leftMouseButtonPressed = false`, and then in the if statement, just check `if leftMouseButtonPressed`.